# MYSQL: How to handle multiple values in one to many table JOIN

Tags: mysql, group-by

I am having trouble figuring out how to capture multiple values from a JOIN.  Should not be that difficult but somehow I can't remember how to do this.

```
Authors:

id | authorname

Books

id ] authorid |bookname

SELECT a.*,b.*  
FROM authors `a`
LEFT JOIN books `b` 
ON a.id = b.authorid 
WHERE a.id = 1
GROUP BY a.id
```

This is only returning the first book by the author, not all of them.

This is not the entire query as there are some other things going on such as publisher, last ordered etc so that I want to group it by author.  Also, the response is getting JSONencoded and sent to an app.  For this reason, I don't want the query to return rows for every book if possible as this would complicated the jsonencoding and api.

I just want to figure out how to capture the multiple books by the author and hold them in some sort of array so that they can be decoded later.

Thanks for any ideas on the right way to to this.

EDIT:

Solved with group_concat(b.bookname) as `book names`, ...
This puts the multiple values in a comma delimited list.

Comment: Loose the GROUP BY and see what that does

Comment: It prints out a record for every book.  It does get all the books but the records no longer correspond to author and this is for an author page (with books for that author listed.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to remove your `GROUP BY` clause, because you really don't need that.

```
SELECT a.*,b.*  
FROM authors `a`
LEFT JOIN books `b` 
ON a.id = b.authorid 
WHERE a.id = 1
```

You are not using any aggregate functions so you don't need to group the result-set into a single row for the grouped column.

Comment: When I take out GROUP BY I get a record for each book.  So if there are three books, there are three records for the author.  If there are two books, there are two records for the author.  This messes up the display of the authors.

Comment: Then you had better show us the PHP code you are using to process the result. And also the result that you want

Comment: @zztop this is the expected behaviour. If you want to have a single row for each author, then add the `GROUP BY` and use __aggregate functions__ like `array_agg()` to retrieve information about all books. Your question seems not to be `SQL`-only.

Comment: Will research array_agg but group_concat working for time being.  Thx!